# Is the Laravel APP_URL env the same as API host?

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel + PHP noob here. Two questions.

1. My APIs are on `http://mydomain.dev:9000`. Is the APP_URL supposed to be the API host, or is it the URL that the end user would be pointing to our application i.e. `http://mydomain.dev` (without the port)?
2. How exactly is the APP_URL being used by Laravel?

Answer (score 1):

It is used when you create assets links, creating links, in the Dusk, default email templates etc. For example:

```
{{ asset('css/some-style.css') }}
```